# How to install RabbitMQ on Docker?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm attempting to install RabbitMQ inside a Docker container using an Ubuntu 18.04 image for running unittests against it.

To install, I'm running the normal `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`, and it appears to install fine, but when I attempt to start or communicate with the service, I get the error:

```
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@b562da1810ce: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@b562da1810ce]

rabbit@b562da1810ce:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on b562da1810ce
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-69@b562da1810ce'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: YUZIPS6zyhfUBX5afdKGcw==
```

Researching the "please check the Erlang cookie" text gets me a ton of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874958/rabbitmq-failed-to-start-tcp-connection-succeeded-but-erlang-distribution-faile), none of which seem to apply to Docker or my situation.

I've tried deleting the `~/.erlang.cookie` then restarting the service, and completely purging the package and reinstalling. Nothing's worked.

How do I run RabbitMQ inside Docker?

Edit: This is my install procedure.

```
root@b562da1810ce:$ sudo apt-get purge -yq rabbitmq-server
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-corba erlang-crypto erlang-diameter erlang-edoc erlang-eldap erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssh
  erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools erlang-xmerl libodbc1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rabbitmq-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,678 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 69832 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rabbitmq-server (3.6.10-1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
(Reading database ... 69618 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for rabbitmq-server (3.6.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.33) ...
root@b562da1810ce:$ rm -Rf /var/log/rabbitmq/*
root@b562da1810ce:$ sudo apt-get install -yq rabbitmq-server
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rabbitmq-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,625 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,678 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 rabbitmq-server all 3.6.10-1 [4,625 kB]
Fetched 4,625 kB in 4s (1,070 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package rabbitmq-server.
(Reading database ... 69613 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rabbitmq-server_3.6.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking rabbitmq-server (3.6.10-1) ...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.6.10-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rabbitmq-server.service → /lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.33) ...
root@b562da1810ce:$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node rabbit@b562da1810ce
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@b562da1810ce: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@b562da1810ce]

rabbit@b562da1810ce:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on b562da1810ce
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-30@b562da1810ce'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: DHe9O00f7sIHn/dTThKVVQ==

root@b562da1810ce:$ sudo service rabbitmq-server start 
 * Starting RabbitMQ Messaging Server rabbitmq-server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [fail]
root@b562da1810ce:$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node rabbit@b562da1810ce
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@b562da1810ce: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@b562da1810ce]

rabbit@b562da1810ce:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on b562da1810ce
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-13@b562da1810ce'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: DHe9O00f7sIHn/dTThKVVQ==
root@b562da1810ce:$ cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err 
root@b562da1810ce:$ cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log 
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "b562da1810ce"
```

Based on the last line from the log, I decided to check `ps aux|grep -i rabbit`, which shows Rabbit is running. Yet neither `service` nor `rabbitmqctl` is able to communicate with it. Why is this?

Comment: How are you trying to start the service?

Comment: @larsks `sudo service rabbitmq-server start`

Comment: Could you update your question to show the exact sequence of commands that you're running? If I start an Ubuntu 18.04 container, run `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install rabbitmq-server`, then `service rabbitmq-server start` it all seems to work, and `rabbitmqctl status` is able to communicate with the server.

Comment: @larsks I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Either use official docker image from [https://hub.docker.com/*/rabbitmq*](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) or yo can use the Dockerfile from [https://hub.docker.com//rabbitmq](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/master/3.7-rc/alpine/Dockerfile)

```
# Alpine Linux is not officially supported by the RabbitMQ team -- use at your own risk!
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN apk add --no-cache \
# grab su-exec for easy step-down from root
        'su-exec>=0.2' \
# bash for docker-entrypoint.sh
        bash \
# "ps" for "rabbitmqctl wait" (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/162)
        procps

# Default to a PGP keyserver that pgp-happy-eyeballs recognizes, but allow for substitutions locally
ARG PGP_KEYSERVER=ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
# If you are building this image locally and are getting `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data` errors,
# run the build with a different PGP_KEYSERVER, e.g. docker build --tag rabbitmq:3.7 --build-arg PGP_KEYSERVER=pgpkeys.eu 3.7/ubuntu
# For context, see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/4252

# Using the latest OpenSSL LTS release, with support until September 2023 - https://www.openssl.org/source/
ENV OPENSSL_VERSION 1.1.1d
ENV OPENSSL_SOURCE_SHA256="1e3a91bc1f9dfce01af26026f856e064eab4c8ee0a8f457b5ae30b40b8b711f2"
# https://www.openssl.org/community/omc.html
ENV OPENSSL_PGP_KEY_IDS="0x8657ABB260F056B1E5190839D9C4D26D0E604491 0x5B2545DAB21995F4088CEFAA36CEE4DEB00CFE33 0xED230BEC4D4F2518B9D7DF41F0DB4D21C1D35231 0xC1F33DD8CE1D4CC613AF14DA9195C48241FBF7DD 0x7953AC1FBC3DC8B3B292393ED5E9E43F7DF9EE8C 0xE5E52560DD91C556DDBDA5D02064C53641C25E5D"

# Use the latest stable Erlang/OTP release (https://github.com/erlang/otp/tags)
ENV OTP_VERSION 22.1.8
# TODO add PGP checking when the feature will be added to Erlang/OTP's build system
# http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2019-January/097067.html
ENV OTP_SOURCE_SHA256="7302be70cee2c33689bf2c2a3e7cfee597415d0fb3e4e71bd3e86bd1eff9cfdc"

# Install dependencies required to build Erlang/OTP from source
# http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html
# autoconf: Required to configure Erlang/OTP before compiling
# dpkg-dev: Required to set up host & build type when compiling Erlang/OTP
# gnupg: Required to verify OpenSSL artefacts
# libncurses5-dev: Required for Erlang/OTP new shell & observer_cli - https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        autoconf \
        ca-certificates \
        dpkg-dev dpkg \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libc-dev \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        ncurses-dev \
    ; \
    \
    OPENSSL_SOURCE_URL="https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz"; \
    OPENSSL_PATH="/usr/local/src/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION"; \
    OPENSSL_CONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/etc/ssl; \
    \
# /usr/local/src doesn't exist in Alpine by default
    mkdir /usr/local/src; \
    \
# Required by the crypto & ssl Erlang/OTP applications
    wget --output-document "$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz.asc" "$OPENSSL_SOURCE_URL.asc"; \
    wget --output-document "$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz" "$OPENSSL_SOURCE_URL"; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    for key in $OPENSSL_PGP_KEY_IDS; do \
        gpg --batch --keyserver "$PGP_KEYSERVER" --recv-keys "$key"; \
    done; \
    gpg --batch --verify "$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz.asc" "$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz"; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME"; \
    echo "$OPENSSL_SOURCE_SHA256 *$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p "$OPENSSL_PATH"; \
    tar --extract --file "$OPENSSL_PATH.tar.gz" --directory "$OPENSSL_PATH" --strip-components 1; \
    \
# Configure OpenSSL for compilation
    cd "$OPENSSL_PATH"; \
# OpenSSL's "config" script uses a lot of "uname"-based target detection...
    MACHINE="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU)" \
    RELEASE="4.x.y-z" \
    SYSTEM='Linux' \
    BUILD='???' \
    ./config \
        --openssldir="$OPENSSL_CONFIG_DIR" \
# add -rpath to avoid conflicts between our OpenSSL's "libssl.so" and the libssl package by making sure /usr/local/lib is searched first (but only for Erlang/OpenSSL to avoid issues with other tools using libssl; https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/364)
        -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib \
    ; \
# Compile, install OpenSSL, verify that the command-line works & development headers are present
    make -j "$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"; \
    make install_sw install_ssldirs; \
    cd ..; \
    rm -rf "$OPENSSL_PATH"*; \
# use Alpine's CA certificates
    rmdir "$OPENSSL_CONFIG_DIR/certs" "$OPENSSL_CONFIG_DIR/private"; \
    ln -sf /etc/ssl/certs /etc/ssl/private "$OPENSSL_CONFIG_DIR"; \
# smoke test
    openssl version; \
    \
    OTP_SOURCE_URL="https://github.com/erlang/otp/archive/OTP-$OTP_VERSION.tar.gz"; \
    OTP_PATH="/usr/local/src/otp-$OTP_VERSION"; \
    \
# Download, verify & extract OTP_SOURCE
    mkdir -p "$OTP_PATH"; \
    wget --output-document "$OTP_PATH.tar.gz" "$OTP_SOURCE_URL"; \
    echo "$OTP_SOURCE_SHA256 *$OTP_PATH.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    tar --extract --file "$OTP_PATH.tar.gz" --directory "$OTP_PATH" --strip-components 1; \
    \
# Configure Erlang/OTP for compilation, disable unused features & applications
# http://erlang.org/doc/applications.html
# ERL_TOP is required for Erlang/OTP makefiles to find the absolute path for the installation
    cd "$OTP_PATH"; \
    export ERL_TOP="$OTP_PATH"; \
    ./otp_build autoconf; \
    export CFLAGS='-g -O2'; \
# add -rpath to avoid conflicts between our OpenSSL's "libssl.so" and the libssl package by making sure /usr/local/lib is searched first (but only for Erlang/OpenSSL to avoid issues with other tools using libssl; https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/364)
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib"; \
    hostArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)"; \
    buildArch="$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)"; \
    dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; dpkgArch="${dpkgArch##*-}"; \
    ./configure \
        --host="$hostArch" \
        --build="$buildArch" \
        --disable-dynamic-ssl-lib \
        --disable-hipe \
        --disable-sctp \
        --disable-silent-rules \
        --enable-clock-gettime \
        --enable-hybrid-heap \
        --enable-kernel-poll \
        --enable-shared-zlib \
        --enable-smp-support \
        --enable-threads \
        --with-microstate-accounting=extra \
        --without-common_test \
        --without-debugger \
        --without-dialyzer \
        --without-diameter \
        --without-edoc \
        --without-erl_docgen \
        --without-erl_interface \
        --without-et \
        --without-eunit \
        --without-ftp \
        --without-hipe \
        --without-jinterface \
        --without-megaco \
        --without-observer \
        --without-odbc \
        --without-reltool \
        --without-ssh \
        --without-tftp \
        --without-wx \
    ; \
# Compile & install Erlang/OTP
    make -j "$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)" GEN_OPT_FLGS="-O2 -fno-strict-aliasing"; \
    make install; \
    cd ..; \
    rm -rf \
        "$OTP_PATH"* \
        /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/*/examples \
        /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/*/src \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .otp-run-deps $runDeps; \
    apk del --no-network .build-deps; \
    \
# Check that OpenSSL still works after purging build dependencies
    openssl version; \
# Check that Erlang/OTP crypto & ssl were compiled against OpenSSL correctly
    erl -noshell -eval 'io:format("~p~n~n~p~n~n", [crypto:supports(), ssl:versions()]), init:stop().'

ENV RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/rabbitmq
# Create rabbitmq system user & group, fix permissions & allow root user to connect to the RabbitMQ Erlang VM
RUN set -eux; \
    addgroup -g 101 -S rabbitmq; \
    adduser -u 100 -S -h "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR" -G rabbitmq rabbitmq; \
    mkdir -p "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR" /etc/rabbitmq /tmp/rabbitmq-ssl /var/log/rabbitmq; \
    chown -fR rabbitmq:rabbitmq "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR" /etc/rabbitmq /tmp/rabbitmq-ssl /var/log/rabbitmq; \
    chmod 777 "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR" /etc/rabbitmq /tmp/rabbitmq-ssl /var/log/rabbitmq; \
    ln -sf "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR/.erlang.cookie" /root/.erlang.cookie

# Use the latest stable RabbitMQ release (https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html)
ENV RABBITMQ_VERSION 3.7.23-rc.1
# https://www.rabbitmq.com/signatures.html#importing-gpg
ENV RABBITMQ_PGP_KEY_ID="0x0A9AF2115F4687BD29803A206B73A36E6026DFCA"
ENV RABBITMQ_HOME=/opt/rabbitmq

# Add RabbitMQ to PATH, send all logs to TTY
ENV PATH=$RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin:$PATH \
    RABBITMQ_LOGS=- RABBITMQ_SASL_LOGS=-

# Install RabbitMQ
RUN set -eux; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        gnupg \
        xz \
    ; \
    \
    RABBITMQ_SOURCE_URL="https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v$RABBITMQ_VERSION/rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-latest-toolchain-$RABBITMQ_VERSION.tar.xz"; \
    RABBITMQ_PATH="/usr/local/src/rabbitmq-$RABBITMQ_VERSION"; \
    \
    wget --output-document "$RABBITMQ_PATH.tar.xz.asc" "$RABBITMQ_SOURCE_URL.asc"; \
    wget --output-document "$RABBITMQ_PATH.tar.xz" "$RABBITMQ_SOURCE_URL"; \
    \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$RABBITMQ_PGP_KEY_ID"; \
    gpg --batch --verify "$RABBITMQ_PATH.tar.xz.asc" "$RABBITMQ_PATH.tar.xz"; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME"; \
    \
    mkdir -p "$RABBITMQ_HOME"; \
    tar --extract --file "$RABBITMQ_PATH.tar.xz" --directory "$RABBITMQ_HOME" --strip-components 1; \
    rm -rf "$RABBITMQ_PATH"*; \
# Do not default SYS_PREFIX to RABBITMQ_HOME, leave it empty
    grep -qE '^SYS_PREFIX=\$\{RABBITMQ_HOME\}$' "$RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmq-defaults"; \
    sed -i 's/^SYS_PREFIX=.*$/SYS_PREFIX=/' "$RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmq-defaults"; \
    grep -qE '^SYS_PREFIX=$' "$RABBITMQ_HOME/sbin/rabbitmq-defaults"; \
    chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq "$RABBITMQ_HOME"; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps; \
    \
# verify assumption of no stale cookies
    [ ! -e "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR/.erlang.cookie" ]; \
# Ensure RabbitMQ was installed correctly by running a few commands that do not depend on a running server, as the rabbitmq user
# If they all succeed, it's safe to assume that things have been set up correctly
    su-exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl help; \
    su-exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl list_ciphers; \
    su-exec rabbitmq rabbitmq-plugins list; \
# no stale cookies
    rm "$RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR/.erlang.cookie"

# Added for backwards compatibility - users can simply COPY custom plugins to /plugins
RUN ln -sf /opt/rabbitmq/plugins /plugins

# set home so that any `--user` knows where to put the erlang cookie
ENV HOME $RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR
# Hint that the data (a.k.a. home dir) dir should be separate volume
VOLUME $RABBITMQ_DATA_DIR

# warning: the VM is running with native name encoding of latin1 which may cause Elixir to malfunction as it expects utf8. Please ensure your locale is set to UTF-8 (which can be verified by running "locale" in your shell)
# Setting all environment variables that control language preferences, behaviour differs - https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable
# https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/ubuntu/#locales
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 4369 5671 5672 25672
CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

Use command to build the container (dot is to locate the Dockerfile in current directory).

```
docker build .
```

Once the image is built then you can use following command to start the container

```
docker container start youtImageName
```

Comment: Part of my goal is to test my RabbitMQ install procedure, so I have to be able to install it on an arbitrary image. Starting with a prebuild image defeats the purpose.

Comment: The above Dockerfile is installing a RabbitMQ by downloading the things and setting up docker image by installing everything manually.