# RabbitMQ: node is unreachable on windows after update

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

My windows machine recently auto-updated, and since then rabbitmq is not working. I know the errors I'm getting appear in many stackoverflow questions, but none of them have helped me resolve my issue. Any `rabbitmqctl` command I run returns the same result, that the node is unreachable (see below).

What I want to know:

1. How can I diagnose my issue?
2. Where can I find rabbitmq or erlang logs for what is happening? I can't find any and the only environment variable defined on my machine is the RABBIT_MQ_HOME var.
3. Any suggestions on fixing the issue (I have listed what I have tried below).

The error I am getting on any `rabbitmqctl` command:

```
rabbitmqctl.bat start_app
Starting node rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM ...
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM']

rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on DESKTOP-BG3LMOM
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on DESKTOP-BG3LMOM
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-352-rabbit@DESKTOP-BG3LMOM'
```

System information:

- RabbitMQ version: 3.9.13
- Erlang version: 12.0
- Windows 10 build: 19044.1526

What I have tried:

- I've checked the erlang cookie is synced in all locations
- I've uninstalled RabbitMQ and Erlang and reinstalled them both to the latest version (via choco), with machine restarts between uninstalling and reinstalling.
- Followed every suggestion listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874958/rabbitmq-failed-to-start-tcp-connection-succeeded-but-erlang-distribution-faile)